# Reading only specific portion of a text file and output them to diffrent text files

Tags: python, loops, split, large-data, lammps

I have a a big text file which content something of the following:

```
158 lines of Text
2000 lines of Data
140 lines of Text
2000 lines of Data
140  lines of Text
.
.
.
```

There is a total of 5 set of 2000 lines of data which I would like python to read and write to 5 different text files. 
Something like this:

```
Data1.txt
Data2.txt
Data3.txt
.
.
```

Browsing online I found the following: [reading sections from a large text file in python efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694798/reading-sections-from-a-large-text-file-in-python-efficiently)

```
def get_block(beg,end):
   output=open("Output.txt",'a')
   with open("input.txt",'r') as f:
      for line in f:
         line=line.strip("\r\n")
         line=line.split("\t")
         position=str(line[0])
         if int(position)<=beg:
            pass
         elif int(position)>=end:
            break
         else:
            for i in line:
               output.write(("%s\t")%(i))
            output.write("\n")
```

Which problem is similar to mine, however, this function I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/aperego/Desktop/HexaPaper/DataToPlot/ReadThermo.py", line 8, in get_block
    if int(position)<=beg:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'LAMMPS (5 Jun 2019)'
```

Which i believe is due to the fact that my input text file has lot of lines of text between the set of data. Also it only accept a single interval of lines, while I'd like my script to run and extract all the lines containing data at once.

I don't know if modifying this script is the best way to approach this problem or if there are better way to achieve my desired goal. Any helps is appreciated!

Comment: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: " in which line of code?

Comment: Hi there, I am not sure I understand what you are tying to do, would you care to elaborate a bit more, please? Thanks.

Comment: error means that you try convert empty string `int("")` . Checke `print(position)` before `int(position)`

Comment: @LuísFlávioFerranteMarcos I have this big text file in which my data are separated by lines of text, I am trying to have python go through the file, select the various intervals of data i need and write it to a new text file.

Comment: @ElisByberi I modified the entry so you can see the full error

Comment: so your error shows that you try do convert to integer `int("LAMMPS (5 Jun 2019)")`. So problem is text in file which doesn't match to your expectation.

Comment: if you know how many lines you have to read then use - ie. `for _ in range(158)` to read first 158 lines. And later `for _ in range(2000)` to read 2000 lines of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how many lines to skip and how many to read then use `for`-loop with `next()` to skip lines and `readline()` to read lines

```
# fin - file input
# fout - file output

fin = open('input.txt')

# skip 158 lines
for _ in range(158):
    next(fin)

# write 2000 lines    
with open('Data1.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for _ in range(2000):
        fout.write(fin.readline())

# skip 140 lines
for _ in range(140):
    next(fin)

# write 2000 lines    
with open('Data2.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for _ in range(2000):
        fout.write(fin.readline())

# ... rest ...

fin.close()
```

---

You could also reduce it to

```
fin = open('test.txt')

# skip 158 lines
for _ in range(158):
    next(fin)

# write 2000 lines    
with open('Data1.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for _ in range(2000):
        fout.write(fin.readline())

# --- the same number of lines to skip

for x in range(2, 5):    
    filename = 'Data{}.txt'.format(x)

    # skip 140 lines
    for _ in range(140):
        next(fin)

    # write 2000 lines
    with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
        for _ in range(2000):
            fout.write(fin.readline())

fin.close()
```